# Delete old fetching items in Swift struct

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, struct, google-cloud-firestore

I have a struct model in my Swift projects that read data from firestore database.
I have inserted a bad item and now my app crash every time, even if i delete this item from the firestore console.
The error in my log console is Fatal error: Unable to initialize type Ordine with dictionary.
And it is always the same bad item.
How can i delete old fetching data from my project?

This is my code in my viewcontroller:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        self.listener =  query?.addSnapshotListener { (documents, error) in
            guard let snapshot = documents else {
                print("Error fetching documents results: \(error!)")
                return
            }

            let results = snapshot.documents.map { (document) -> Ordine in
                if let ordine = Ordine(dictionary: document.data(), id: document.documentID) {
                    return ordine
                } else {
                    fatalError("Unable to initialize type \(Ordine.self) with dictionary \(document.data())")
                }
            }

            self.ordini = results
            self.documents = snapshot.documents
            self.TableView.reloadData()

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe Firestore stores locally as well, so it's possible it is still trying to find something that is either not there or still faulty. I would try deleting the build from your device/sim (this will clear out your bad data) and re-run.

Comment: thanks. I was trying to rebuild and close and reopen xcode but it didn't work. All I have to do was delete app from the device.

Comment: awesome! glad it helped